# WPF looks win98'ish with custom ms-style

Tags: c#, wpf, msstyles

When I apply a custom msstyle on my system (any msstyle) all WPF components change their appearance to this:

[image]Why it's happening?
Any way to solve it?

Comment: use custom styles, so controls will have the same UI on different OS setups. Sometimes I use WPFToolkit: http://wpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/11/02/getting-aero-theme-with-wpf-on-windows-xp/), you can do the following in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />    
</Application.Resources>
```

I tesed it by setting my Window 7 Theme to "Windows-Classic". The controls still have the Windows 7 look.